# Read Data from SQL Server only can Integer

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio

I have program to read data from SQL Server but I just can read data only integer when I want to read data varchar have error in my code.

My Code:

```
con.Open()
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(("SELECT id, Cash FROM tbl_UserStatus WHERE id= " & TextBox1.Text), con)
Dim myreader As SqlDataReader
myreader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
myreader.Read()
If myreader.HasRows Then
    TextBox2.Text = myreader.Item("id").ToString
    TextBox3.Text = myreader.Item("Cash").ToString
End If
con.Close()
TextBox1.Clear()
```

When I read data id Integer like `2222` the code work, but when I read data id varchar like `ace143` have error

My Data: http://prntscr.com/8xe7xc

Error: http://prntscr.com/8x5r9s

Answer (score 0):

If you have strings in SQL, you have to enclose them into `'`s, so you'll have to do this:

```
"...WHERE id= '" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
```

But please don't do this, it makes your application vulnerable for SQL injection, you should use parameters instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SqlParameter`. You can define a type for SqlParameter and SqlValue will be generated properly.
Also using `SqlParameter` will save from Sql injection, as @JamesZ mentioned

```vb
con.Open()
Dim query As String = "SELECT id, Cash FROM tbl_UserStatus WHERE id=@ID"
Using cmd As New SqlCommand(query, con)
    'Create parameter for query
    Dim param As New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@ID",
                                        .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar,
                                        .Value = TextBox1.Text}
    'Add created parameter to the command
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param)
    Using myreader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        If myreader.HasRows Then
            If myreader.Read() = true Then
                TextBox2.Text = myreader.Item("id").ToString
                TextBox3.Text = myreader.Item("Cash").ToString 
            End If
        End If
    End Using
End Using 'SqlCommand need to be disposed too
con.Close()
TextBox1.Clear()
```

Comment: You need to read data before using: `myreader.Read()`. [SqlDataReader Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: how if i use 2 parameter?

Comment: Create and add second parameter to the `cmd.Parameters` collection. [SqlCommand.Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)